# Competition with two methods and run completion method once

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have three methods, two of them run at the same time. And the third method should be started only when the first and second method together complete their work. Either the first or second method, competitors, can finish their work first.

```
- (void)method1 {
        //DO Long Work
        isMethod1Complete = YES;
        [self method3];
    }

    - (void)method2 {
        //DO Long Work
        isMethod2Complete = YES;
        [self method3];
    }

    - (void)method3 {
        if (isMethod1Complete && isMethod2Complete) {
            //DO Work once
        }
    }
```

Method 3 should always be called once. But the problem is that there is a situation that method1 and method2 have finished working at the same time, and method3 is called twice. Tell me how to solve this problem in objective c for iOS?

Update:A concrete example, I have two services that call delegates when they finish their work.

```
- (void)method1Handler {
        isMethod1Complete = YES;
        [self method3];
}

- (void)method2Handler {
        isMethod1Complete = YES;
        [self method3];
}
```

How can this be solved without blocks?
For blocks, Rob's example is the best.

Comment: Why would you not use blocks? It's the standard way of doing this. Just call your block where you are currently calling `method3`...

Comment: The two services I use are based on delegates and I can not change it = (

Comment: Fine, save your completion handlers in block properties and have your delegates call them from there. Or, save your `dispatch_group_t` variable in a property. But dispatch groups are the best way to keep track of when a series of asynchronous tasks are done. The other options include `NSOperation` dependencies, reactive patterns, etc., but dispatch groups are best. It gets you out of the weeds of maintaining a bunch of state properties (which you likely will have to synchronize to make threadsafe), and its scalable.

Comment: Could you give a small example of how to call a group block in delegates? I tried, I still had a method worked two times. = (

Comment: See my revised answer below where I show two options when using delegate-protocol-based API rather a block-based API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say:

> I have three methods, two of them run at the same time.

That means that they must be asynchronous or running on background queues (otherwise there's no way for them to run at the same time).

So, the idea is that you should give them both completion handlers (which will be called when they're done):

```
- (void)method1WithCompletion:(void(^ _Nonnull)(void))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //DO Long Work asynchronously

        completion();
    });
}

- (void)method2WithCompletion:(void(^ _Nonnull)(void))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //DO Long Work asynchronously

        completion();
    });
}

- (void)method3 {
    // final task
}
```

In the above example, I added explicit `dispatch_async` calls to a background queue to ensure that the two long tasks run asynchronously. But if the code is already doing something asynchronous (e.g. a network request), then you will likely not need these `dispatch_async` calls, but just put the `completion()` call inside the completion handler provided by whatever API you are already using. But without more information about what `method1` and `method2` are doing, I cannot be more specific.

But, setting that aside, once your `method1` and `method2` have their own completion handlers, you can use [`dispatch_group_notify`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452933-dispatch_group_notify?language=occ) to identify what should be done when all of the [`dispatch_group_enter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452803-dispatch_group_enter?language=occ) calls are balanced by their corresponding [`dispatch_group_leave`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452872-dispatch_group_leave?language=objc) calls:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self method1WithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self method2WithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self method3];
});
```

---

In subsequent comments, you mentioned that you are not using a completion block-based API, but rather a delegate-protocol-based API. You have a few options, for example:

1. You can use the same above closure pattern, but just save the completion handlers as block properties, e.g.:

   For example, define block properties:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) void (^completionOne)(void);
   @property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) void (^completionTwo)(void);
   ```

   Then, your `method1` and `method2` would save these blocks:

   ```
   - (void)method1WithCompletion:(void(^ _Nonnull)(void))completion {
       self.completionOne = completion;

       // start your time consuming asynchronous process
   }

   // and your completion delegate method can then call the saved closure
   // and then remove it

   - (void)method1DidComplete {
       self.completionOne();
       self.completionOne = nil;
   }

   - (void)method2WithCompletion:(void(^ _Nonnull)(void))completion {
       self.completionTwo = completion;

       // start second asynchronous process
   }

   // same as above

   - (void)method2DidComplete {
       self.completionTwo();
       self.completionTwo = nil;
   }
   ```

   The delegate-protocol completion API would then just call the saved block properties (and probably reset them to `nil` to free the memory associated with those blocks).

   Then you can use the dispatch group notify process as shown in my original answer, above.
2. Alternatively, rather than using blocks, you can just use dispatch group by itself. For example, define dispatch group property:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) dispatch_group_t group;
   ```

   Then, you create your group and start your two tasks:

   ```
   self.group = dispatch_group_create();

   [self method1];

   [self method2];

   dispatch_group_notify(self.group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self method3];
   });
   ```

   And, the two methods then `dispatch_group_enter` when you start the tasks and `dispatch_group_leave` in their respective completion handler delegate methods:

   ```
   - (void)method1 {
       dispatch_group_enter(self.group);

       // start first asynchronous process
   }

   // in your delegate completion method, you "leave" the group

   - (void)method1DidComplete {
       dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
   }

   - (void)method2 {
       dispatch_group_enter(self.group);

       // start second asynchronous process
   }

   - (void)method2DidComplete {
       dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
   }

   - (void)method3 {
       // you might as well remove the group now that you're done with it

       self.group = nil;

       // final task
       NSLog(@"doing three");
   }
   ```

Personally, I would generally lean towards the first option (that way, the dispatch group stuff is contained in a single method), but either approach works.

Answer (score 1):

Why not dispatching the "call" to method3 in a serial queue?

```
dispatch_queue_t notSimQ;
notSimQ = dispatch_queue_create("notSimQ", NULL);

- (void)method1 {
    //DO Long Work
    isMethod1Complete = YES;
    dispatch_async( notSimQ, // or sync
    ^{ 
      [self method3]; 
    });
}

- (void)method2 { … } // similiasr

- (void)method3 { … } // unchanged
```

The calls to method3 are never in competition.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)method1 {
//DO Long Work
isMethod2Complete = YES;
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
[self method3];
  }
    }

- (void)method2 { … } 

- (void)method3 { … }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self method1];
[self method2];
}


- (void)method1 {
    //DO Long Work
    isMethod1Complete = YES;

}

- (void)method2 {
    //DO Long Work
    isMethod2Complete = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self method3];
  }
}

- (void)method3 {
    if (isMethod1Complete && isMethod2Complete) {
        //DO Work once
    }
}
```

Comment: call method like this